# Excel VBA runs as intended in code editor but not within excel

Tags: excel, code-editor, vba

I have a code that requires to copy range of data from one sheet, paste it in another sheet, then delete it. When I run the code through excel's VBA code editor it works as intended, however, when I run it through the spreadsheet using the forms button it always misses the last column. And it doesn't matter if I increase the column in the range, it always takes one less column than needed. My code sample is below

```
        'Copy Rebar Data
    If RebarRowNumStart <> 0 And RebarRowNumEnd <> 0 Then
    Worksheets("Temp-Data").Range("A" & RebarRowNumStart & ":I" & RebarRowNumEnd).Copy Worksheets("Rebar-Data").Range("A4:I" & (RebarRowNumEnd - RebarRowNumStart + 4))
    End If

    If WeldsRowNumStart <> 0 And WeldsRowNumEnd <> 0 Then
    Worksheets("Temp-Data").Range("A" & WeldsRowNumStart & ":G" & WeldsRowNumEnd).Copy Worksheets("Welds-Data").Range("A4:G" & (WeldsRowNumEnd - WeldsRowNumStart + 4))
    End If

    If EarthingRowNumStart <> 0 And EarthingRowNumEnd <> 0 Then
    Worksheets("Temp-Data").Range("A" & EarthingRowNumStart & ":k" & EarthingRowNumEnd).Copy Worksheets("Earthing Bars").Range("A4:K" & (EarthingRowNumEnd - EarthingRowNumStart + 4))
    End If

    If AnchorRowNumStart <> 0 And AnchorRowNumEnd <> 0 Then
    Worksheets("Temp-Data").Range("A" & AnchorRowNumStart & ":K" & AnchorRowNumEnd).Copy Worksheets("Anchor Plates").Range("A4:K" & (AnchorRowNumEnd - AnchorRowNumStart + 4))
    End If

    If HalfenRowNumStart <> 0 And HalfenRowNumEnd <> 0 Then
    Worksheets("Temp-Data").Range("A" & HalfenRowNumStart & ":K" & HalfenRowNumEnd).Copy Worksheets("Halfen Channels").Range("A4:K" & (HalfenRowNumEnd - HalfenRowNumStart + 4))
    End If

    If ConesRowNumStart <> 0 And ConesRowNumEnd <> 0 Then
    Worksheets("Temp-Data").Range("A" & ConesRowNumStart & ":K" & ConesRowNumEnd).Copy Worksheets("Cones").Range("A4:K" & (ConesRowNumEnd - ConesRowNumStart + 4))
    End If

    'Delete Data
    Range("A2:K" & LastRow).Clear
```

So it works fine when I run in in the code editor but not from clicking the button. Tried to run it on Excel 2007 and 2016, same results. Your help is appreciated.

The purpose of it is to read a bunch of data in a spreadsheet called "Temp-Data" figures out what it corresponds to, then copy them in the right spreadsheet in the same workbook. It works as intended except the part where it doesn't copy / paste / delete the last column ("K"). P.S: It works perfectly when I run through the code editor

Comment: The only place I can see column as a variable is `Worksheets("Temp-Data").Range("A" & EarthingRowNumStart & ":" & ColumnName & EarthingRowNumEnd).Copy Worksheets("Earthing Bars").Range("A4:K" & (EarthingRowNumEnd - EarthingRowNumStart + 4))` What is the value of `ColumnName`?

Comment: BTW are you talking about last column or last row?

Comment: Last column. The column is a variable, but that is not the problem as even if I change it to a fixed string I still get the same error.

Comment: So you are saying that copying Col A:K from one sheet to the another sheet A:K is not working and the data gets pasted to only A:J ?

Comment: Yes...but works fine when I run it through the code editor. I only have this problem when I run it through the click of a button in excel

Comment: You have to do something different then. Do you run through the code always to the end and not stop anywhere? It could happen that it works for a time but you overwrite it somewhere else in your code and get wrong results.

Comment: You don't show us all the code, especially the part where rownumbers are assigned, please add that bit.

Comment: I press the play button in the code editor without having stopping mark, it works as intended. When I press the form button in excel, it doesn't. I read something about the debugger's execution is different than when you run it straight [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom/vba-working-on-f8-step-through-but-not-when-run/27c0d442-5b4f-410b-8505-d642b0bf523e)...Also all the other variables are row numbers which I do not have problem with. The only problem I have is that the VBA code edits one column short